# Trainer Roller : polyurethane or metal?

Tags: trainer

Some trainers come with a polyurethane roller not metal. I think that would be a lot better then the metal one. Has anyone used a polyurethane roller? And if so are they good or just the same as metal when it comes to wear and tear, and slippage ?

Comment: I'd expect the plastic one to generate static where the metal one won't.  And that the plastic one will be slipperier than the metal one.

Comment: I world imagine a plastic one sinks less heat and can't use an eddy current brake, but world maybe be lighter to cart about. The build of the frame is likely to be a bigger issue though, some are pretty flimsy, some overly bulky.

Comment: @alex your point about magnetic braking and resistance is worthy of being an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't had a poly roller for long, only a season but I've never had any issues with slippage, though I always use a trainer tire on it.

Wear and tear I can't note any difference after a season of use other than some dirt and marks from my tire. Nothing deeper than surface dirt. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

I've used Elite and Tacx trainers. The Elite had an elastomer roller and the Tacx a metal one.

The elastomer one is quiet and I do experience slippage on the metal one.
However, they apply pressure to the roller differently. The Elite uses suspended weight of rider and bike - whilst the Tacx uses an adjustable mount rising up to the rear tire. On my Tacx, the small amount of slippage is only for a short period as the tire & me warms up - maybe a few minutes. On the elastomer roller - no slippage, less heat build up too. I could adjust the slippage out - by applying more pressure to the rear - but it is such a VERY small amount - which happens only on out of saddle efforts (calibrating the smart turbo) and is gone after a minute.

Still using the same tyre on both. And have used the tyre for a good few years now.